# How best to install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS only to replace WIN 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 beta 2 dual boot ?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, 14.04

My C: HDD has Win 7 and data files (all backed up several ways)

My D: HDD has Xubuntu 14.04 beta 2 installed in 100GB partition for OS, and also logical partitions E: and F: used for data backup.

What is the best way to install or upgrade to the newly released Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and fully remove WIN 7 Home 64 bit Operating System from C: HDD ? My D; HDD is newer and larger and the Linux OS could stay there, right? It doesn't have to be on the C; HDD when the only OS ?

Thanks for your advice !

Answer (score 0):

- first boot the live ubuntu 14.04
- then format the partation containing xubuntu and win7
- then install the ubuntu 14.04 using [manual partitioning method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation).